# Xamarin XAML pages dissapeared from solutiuon explorer

Tags: xaml, xamarin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibqkl.png)

Hi everyone,
I did something to the solution explorer that make the .xaml files dissappear. The .xaml.cs files are still there and the .xaml pages are just hidden somehow. When i close a new project and open it up again they will appear again.

Does someone know what i did wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I had issues with pages not coming up in the solution explorer it would usually be because something messed up in my csproj file, maybe you can just verify all the files for your project are listed in the csproj file